# Linux on SUA. Any active projects?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-distributions, gnu, sua

I would like to know whether besides the following attempt

http://www.debian-interix.net/

to port the entire set of tools which come with the most popular Linux systems
to Windows systems with SUA (Subsystem for UNIX-applications) support enabled
have been successful and are currently active

(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications ).

Thanks.

Comment: Can't figure out why there seems to be so little interest about SUA on this group (judging from the fact the sua tag has been used very little).

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the fact that sales of the Windows OS have dropped in recent years.

Comment: Note that Linux is the kernel, which cannot run in SUA (which runs on a POSIX subsystem on the NT kernel, beside the Win32 subsystem). You're more looking for the GNU userland.

Comment: Yes. Please take note of the fact that in the above post I spoke of tools, hence all the GNU (and other open sourced utilities such as for example apache which is not GNU) applications which come with Linux. Obviously we wouldn't be installing the Linux kernel as part of such a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUA was dropped for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.

Before that it was available in some form or different name in higher SKUs of Windows and in Windows Server.

Didn't help that MS kept changing what provided Unix support - from MKS Toolkit to Interix (which they bought out).  What killed it I think is virtual machines. No longer need POSIX compatibility in the OS to support it on a server as it can instead done in a VM running a variant of Unix.

Comment: I deeply regret that Windows 8.1 no longer supports SUA. You're right, it's probably virtual machines that killed it.